# Having trouble with Facebook FQL - Empty Return

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I'm attempting to make a Facebook app that will query insights metrics from pages that I administer. I'm unsure if there is a better approach, but I am running into issue after issue trying to build my queries.

For instance, many of the "metric" fields listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights) return empty data objects. Testing the following FQL query on the Graph API Explorer is an example (substitute  with your page ID):

```
fql?q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=<USER_ID> AND metric='post_storytellers' AND period=0
```

I have granted myself "read_insights" permissions.

I'm wondering if this is a common issue, if I'm doing this wrong, and if there is a better way (i.e. FQL is problematic, stick to the Graph API). I started this project using Perl, intending to simply parse the return data into a database. Perhaps I would be better served writing this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post_storytellers metric, has only 3 available periods: day, week and days_28. When you put period=0, you are asking for the lifetime period.
Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=<PAGE_ID> AND metric='page_storytellers' AND end_time=1334905200 AND period=period('week')
```

I hope it would help!